# Class file needed by ExtraImplicits in json spray lenses is missing

Tags: json, scala, spray

I am trying to compile a scala class related to the json spray. Following error message is a bit mystifying to me:

```
error: class file needed by ExtraImplicits is missing.
reference type JsValue of package spray.json refers to nonexisting symbol.

  val tables = json.extract[String](tableLense)
```

Here is scaladoc on the class.
http://jrudolph.github.io/json-lenses/latest/api/cc/spray/json/lenses/ExtraImplicits.html

@Jrudolph:  I had already added maven dependencies as follows:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>net.virtual-void</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lenses_2.9.2</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cc.spray.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>spray-json_2.9.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Looking at my own mvn dependencies, there is apparently a versioning mismatch. Problem is, the last version of cc.spray.json in mvn repo is the one above: but there are many newer ones listed on the project download site.  I would have to use a system path in pom.xml (yuck) or set up a private repo (yuck).

Comment: It seems spray-json itself is missing. What kind of build system do you use?

Comment: i am using maven, added info to the question.

Comment: So, then it's probably because spray-json 1.0.1 isn't fully compatible with the json-lenses version. Can you try spray-json 1.2.3?

Comment: groupid: io.spray, artifactId: spray-json_2.9.2, version: 1.2.3 You may need to add the `repo.spray.io` as a repository.